# The results are filtered in a multiple query on firebase

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angular5

Hi guys I have a problem with a multiple query in the firebase list
This query filters requests by these queries
But it brings me three results and correct there are only two results

```
            this.all_being_executed = this.fdb.list('main_requests', ref => {
              let query = ref.orderByChild('requests_receiving_status').equalTo(false);
                  query = ref.orderByChild('requests_status').equalTo(true);
              return query;
        }).valueChanges();
        return this.all_being_executed;
```

[image]

Is there any help to filter the results correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only one `orderByChild()` clause in your query, so it seems like your second clause is overwritting the first one and you're just getting the ones with `request_status===true`.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data):

> Queries can only order by one key at a time. Calling orderByChild()
>   multiple times on the same query throws an error

My suggestion is to either refactor your current data structure to allow for a simpler query, or use a new third field which concatenates both `requests_receiveing_status` and `request_status`, them do your query on this concatenated field. Something like this:

```
{
  "requests_receiving_status_and_status": "false_true";
}
```

and query it like this:

```
let query = ref.orderByChild('requests_receiving_status_and_status').equalTo('false_true');
```

Now, I know that this seems hacky and non-performant, but it is actually a valid approach for Firebase.

But, if you prefer a cleaner solution, try to separate your objects on two separated lists, one for requests_receiving_status true and the other for the false ones, them search only on the false ones using `query = ref.orderByChild('requests_status').equalTo(true);`. It adds redundancy but it is another valid approach on NoSql databases.

Also, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) and see if it helps you to tackle this issue.